# failed to display variable data types in shiny flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dt, flexdashboard

I am trying to display variable types dynamically and my code is something like this (using into flexdashboard shiny app):

```
tblCls <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
     datatable(head(read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header), 5))

    }
})

output$class <- renderText({
    print(class( tblCls()  ))
  })

textOutput("class")
```

I read the csv file from fileInput method.

The result is expected something what we get when do `str(DF)` in R but what I am getting is `datatables htmlwidget` as output.

Not sure what I have done wrong here, need to understand the correct method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need -

```
tblCls <- reactive({
   req(input$file1) # if else not needed when using req()
   head(read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header = input$header), 5)
})

output$class <- renderPrint({
   str(tblCls())
})

textOutput("class")
```

Comment: this prints to the console rather then to ui (in my case flexdashboard's box)

Comment: @loveR I am not familiar with nuances of `flexdashboard` but above approach is correct from `shiny` perspective. Maybe play with it a bit and see what works.

Comment: I even tried this `output$class <- renderText({
   #str(tblCls())
    print(str( tblCls()  ))
})` but this also prints to console and not on the box

Comment: @loveR I don't know much about `flexdashboard` to advise anything more. Hopefully someone else will chime in and help out.

Comment: using `renderPrint` solved the problem.. I am slowly getting expert with flexdashboard.. hahahaha.